# Update TreeView item graphic

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I can't update dynamically TreeView item graphic when I try to set new image:

```
ImageView imgViesw = new ImageView(new Image(DataTabs.class.getResource("/images/Misc-Database-3-icon.png").toExternalForm()));

treeItem.setGraphic(null);
treeItem.setGraphic(imgViesw);
```

First I generate TreeView with Items using custom Graphics for for tree nodes. This works well.

Then I use JavaFX service to iterate the tree nodes and change the icons based on some condition(active/not-active).

But the images are not updated.

I use Java 8u40b21. Is this a known bug?

Comment: Please consider posting a MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Works fine for me on JDK 8u40b16 (download site is broken right now so I can't test b21). I suspect the bug is in the code you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 1):

After setting the new graphic on the `TreeItem`, refresh the `TreeView`. It works for me.

```
treeItem.setGraphic(imgViesw);    
myTreeView.refresh();
```

Comment: no .. setting the graphic should (and does) update the tree no need to dig out the canon :-) Refresh is a very, very last measure for rare corner cases - f.i. if your data can't be organized to report changes on itself. Don't use for anything else!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're going to have to create a custom cell factory for your tree view to layout your components (set graphic).

See Implementing Cell Factories:

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/tree-view.htm

What I think is happening is that you do indeed change the graphic, however immediately afterwords the tree view's default cell factory recreates the tree item's tree cell and displays that instead.

Comment: `setGraphic(...)` worked just fine for me. It's impossible to know why it didn't work for the OP as he didn't post his code.