# Missing graphics in TreeCells / TreeItems of JavaFX TreeView

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

We have developed a JavaFX application and got some strange behaviour with TreeView and TreeCells:

The graphics of the tree elements are sometimes gone and we do not know the reason.

I created a small repo with a file manager application:

[image]

And we were able to repoduce the problem with this simple example:

[image]

My example is a very limited file manager that displays files and directories in a tree on the left and details on the right side. It allows navigating through the tree, opening and closing directories and using right mouse click for a context menu with file operations. Also drag and drop is allowed as we wanted to implement a small example for that in a TreeView.

The interesting parts are the classes FileTreeCell and FileTreeItem.

In FileTreeCell the drag and drop handler is registered and the method updateItem is overwritten. The implementation of updateItem is based on code from JavaFX tutorial (https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/tree-view.htm).

```
/**
 * Instances of this class are used to render tree items.
 */
public class FileTreeCell extends TreeCell<File> {
    /**
     * Creates a new instance.
     * @param dragHandler the handler this tree cell should notify on drag and drop operations.
     */
    public FileTreeCell(DragDropHandler dragHandler) {
        setOnDragDetected((MouseEvent event) -> dragHandler.handleDragDetected(event, this));
        setOnDragOver((DragEvent event) -> dragHandler.handleDragOver(event, this));
        setOnDragEntered((DragEvent event) -> dragHandler.handleOnDragEntered(event, this));
        setOnDragExited((DragEvent event) -> dragHandler.handleOnDragExited(event, this));
        setOnDragDropped((DragEvent event) -> dragHandler.handleDragDropped(event, this));
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(File file, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(file, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if (file == null) {
                setText("");
            } else {
                setText(file.getName());
                FileTreeItem fileTreeItem = (FileTreeItem) getTreeItem();
                setContextMenu(fileTreeItem.createContextMenu());
            }
            setGraphic(getTreeItem().getGraphic());
        }
    }
}
```

The FileTreeItem is based on documentation from JavaFX API (https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.html). I added code to support lazy loading of a directory when it is expanded in the tree. The load is done asynchronously using a CompletableFuture. The Supplier method (get) and the BiConsumer method (accept) are both implemented in this class to keep things short and easy. Also an hour glass icon is shown during load that is animated until load is completed.

```
/**
 * Instances of this class are used as tree items in the FileManager navigation.
 * 
 * Base on https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.html
 */
public class FileTreeItem extends TreeItem<File> implements Supplier<File[]>, BiConsumer<File[], Throwable> {
    /** The folder icon image. */
    private static final Image FOLDER_ICON = new Image(FileTreeItem.class.getResourceAsStream("folder.png"));
    /** The file icon image. */
    private static final Image FILE_ICON = new Image(FileTreeItem.class.getResourceAsStream("file.png"));
    /** The hour glass icon image. */
    private static final Image HOURGLASS_ICON = new Image(FileTreeItem.class.getResourceAsStream("hourglass.png"));
    /** Cache flag for leaf (plain file) or not (directory). */
    private boolean isLeaf;
    /** Indicator used to do leaf testing only once. */
    private boolean isFirstTimeLeaf = true;
    /** A completable future used for asynchronous loading. */
    private CompletableFuture<File[]> completableFuture;
    /** Time line used for animation. */
    private Timeline timeLine;
    /** A dialog handler used to show dialogs. */
    private DialogHandler dialogHandler;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance.
     * @param file the underlying file.
     * @param dialogHandler the dialog handler used to show dialogs.
     */
    public FileTreeItem(File file, DialogHandler dialogHandler) {
        super(file, new ImageView(file.isDirectory() ? FOLDER_ICON : FILE_ICON));
        this.dialogHandler = dialogHandler;
        expandedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldEpxanded,
                    Boolean newExpanded) {
                if (newExpanded != null && newExpanded.booleanValue()) {
                    applyGraphic(HOURGLASS_ICON, true);
                    completableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(FileTreeItem.this);
                    completableFuture.whenComplete(FileTreeItem.this);
                } else
                    getChildren().clear();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLeaf() {
        if (isFirstTimeLeaf) {
            isFirstTimeLeaf = false;
            File f = (File) getValue();
            isLeaf = f.isFile();
        }
        return isLeaf;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getValue().getName();
    }

    /**
     * Reloads this tree item.
     */
    public void refresh() {
        setExpanded(false);
        setExpanded(true);
    }

    /**
     * Loads the children of a directory.
     * 
     * The method implements the Supplier interface and is invoked asynchronously.
     * 
     * Any RunTimeExceptions and Errors thrown inside this method will be forwarded
     * to the BiConsumer method.
     */
    @Override
    public File[] get() {
        File[] retval = new File[0];
        File file = getValue();
        if (file != null && file.isDirectory()) {
            retval = file.listFiles();
            if (retval == null)
                retval = new File[0];
            else
                Arrays.sort(retval);
        }
        return retval;
    }

    /**
     * Handles the result after loading the children of a directory.
     * 
     * The method implements the BiConsumer interface.
     * 
     * @param files     the loaded children of a directory.
     * @param throwable any Throwable thrown during the load operation or null if
     *                  load was successful.
     */
    @Override
    public void accept(File[] files, Throwable throwable) {
        if (throwable != null) {
            dialogHandler.showError(throwable);
            resetFolderIcon();
        } else {
            try {
                // avoid NullPointerException
                if (files == null)
                    files = new File[0];
                // create FileTreeItem container for all files (outside JavaFX thread)
                FileTreeItem[] treeItems = new FileTreeItem[files.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
                    treeItems[i] = new FileTreeItem(files[i], dialogHandler);
                // add all children to this item (in JavaFX thread)
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        getChildren().setAll(treeItems);
                        resetFolderIcon();
                    }

                });
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                dialogHandler.showError(e);
                resetFolderIcon();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether this FileTreeItem is an ancestor of another FileTreeItem.
     * @param other the other FileTreeItem.
     * @return true, if this FileTreeItem is an ancestor of other FileTreeItem, false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isAncestor(FileTreeItem other) {
        FileTreeItem current = other;
        FileTreeItem last = null;
        boolean retval = false;
        while (current != null && last != current) {
            if (equals(current)) {
                retval = true;
                break;
            }
            last = current;
            current = (FileTreeItem) current.getParent();
        }
        return retval;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a context menu for this FileTreeItem.
     * @return a context menu for this FileTreeItem.
     */
    public ContextMenu createContextMenu() {
        ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        ObservableList<MenuItem> menuItems = contextMenu.getItems();
        if (getValue().isDirectory()) {
            /*
             * Refresh Action
             */
            MenuItem refresh = new MenuItem("Refresh");
            menuItems.add(refresh);
            // We simply close and reopen the folder tree item which will empty the children
            // list.
            // But only if it was already open before refresh.
            refresh.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    if (isExpanded()) {
                        refresh();
                    }
                }
            });
            /*
             * Separator
             */
            SeparatorMenuItem separatorMenuItem = new SeparatorMenuItem();
            menuItems.add(separatorMenuItem);
            /*
             * Create New File Action
             */
            MenuItem newFile = new MenuItem("New File");
            menuItems.add(newFile);
            newFile.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    File dir = getValue();
                    if (!dir.isDirectory())
                        return;
                    String fileName = dialogHandler.showTextInputDialog("New File", "Creating New File", "Please enter name of new file:", "file.txt");
                    if (fileName == null)
                        return;
                    File file = new File(dir, fileName);
                    try {
                        if (file.exists()) {
                            dialogHandler.showAlert(AlertType.WARNING, "Warning", "File exists: " + file.getName(),
                                    "Sorry, ignoring your request because file already exists!");
                        } else {
                            file.createNewFile();
                            FileTreeItem newTreeItem = new FileTreeItem(file, dialogHandler);
                            ObservableList<TreeItem<File>> children = getChildren();
                            children.add(newTreeItem);
                            children.sort(Util.COMPARATOR);
                        }
                        setExpanded(true);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        dialogHandler.showAlert(AlertType.ERROR, "Error", "Error creating File: " + file.getName(),
                                "Sorry, failed to create file: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
            /*
             * Create New Directory Action
             */
            MenuItem newDir = new MenuItem("New Directory");
            menuItems.add(newDir);
            newDir.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    File dir = getValue();
                    if (!dir.isDirectory())
                        return;
                    String dirName = dialogHandler.showTextInputDialog("New Directory", "Creating New Directory", "Please enter name of new directory:", "directory");
                    if (dirName == null)
                        return;
                    File file = new File(dir, dirName);
                    if (file.exists()) {
                        dialogHandler.showAlert(AlertType.WARNING, "Warning", "Directory exists: " + file.getName(),
                                "Sorry, ignoring your request because directory already exists!");
                    } else {
                        boolean success = file.mkdir();
                        if (!success) {
                            dialogHandler.showAlert(AlertType.ERROR, "Error",
                                    "Error creating Directory: " + file.getName(),
                                    "Sorry, failed to create directory!");
                        } else {
                            FileTreeItem newTreeItem = new FileTreeItem(file, dialogHandler);
                            ObservableList<TreeItem<File>> children = getChildren();
                            children.add(newTreeItem);
                            children.sort(Util.COMPARATOR);
                        }
                    }
                    setExpanded(true);
                }
            });
        }
        /*
         * Delete File Action
         */
        MenuItem deleteFile = new MenuItem("Delete");
        menuItems.add(deleteFile);
        deleteFile.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                File file = getValue();
                boolean result = dialogHandler.showConfirmation("Delete File", "Delete File: " + file.getName(),
                        "Are you sure?");
                if (result) {
                    boolean delete = file.delete();
                    if (!delete) {
                        dialogHandler.showAlert(AlertType.ERROR, "Error", "Error deleting File: " + file.getName(),
                                "Sorry, deletion failed! Maybe non-empty directory?");
                    } else {
                        FileTreeItem parent = (FileTreeItem) getParent();
                        parent.getChildren().remove(FileTreeItem.this);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        return contextMenu;
    }

    // private methods

    /**
     * Sets the icon of this FileTreeItem.
     * @param image the icon of this FileTreeItem.
     */
    private void applyGraphic(Image image) {
        applyGraphic(image, false);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the icon of this FileTreeItem.
     * @param image the icon of this FileTreeItem.
     * @param animate true, if the icon should be animated.
     */
    private void applyGraphic(Image image, boolean animate) {
        ImageView icon = new ImageView(image);
        setGraphic(icon);
        if (animate) {
            timeLine = new Timeline(
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0), new KeyValue(icon.rotateProperty(), 0)),
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), new KeyValue(icon.rotateProperty(), 360)));
            timeLine.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
            timeLine.play();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Resets the folder icon to its default and stops the animation.
    */
    private void resetFolderIcon() {
        timeLine.stop();
        applyGraphic(FOLDER_ICON);
    }
}
```

I do not create new ImagesIcons when updateItem in TreeCell is called. I am using the graphics from TreeItem that have been created recently in the constructor or during start and stop of the load process. I thought that this is the correct approach according to the documentation and the tutorial. Am I right?

The whole project can be found at GitHub:

- https://github.com/treimers/FileManager.

I found two bugs looking similar to my problem:

- https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8209017
- https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8190331

Am I running into the same or a similar problem?

My environment

Java
openjdk version "15.0.2" 2021-01-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 15.0.2+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 15.0.2+7, mixed mode, sharing)

JavaFX
17.0.8

Should I give JavaFX 20 a try where the first bug was fixed?

And I found this thread where a TreeView.refresh is recommended, but discouraged in an answer below:

- [Update TreeView item graphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27984156/update-treeview-item-graphic)

Comment: I have a vague notion in my head that I've run into issues with `TreeView` / `TreeTableView` graphics in the past. I can't remember if I found the issue came with relying on the graphic property of the items or not. What happens if you don't set any `TreeItem.graphic` property and instead have the `TreeCell` implementation be entirely responsible for setting the correct graphic?

Comment: *"Should I give JavaFX 20 a try where the first bug was fixed?"* -> Of course.  If you suspect a bug in the platform, then test with the most recent version (currently 21 for JDK and JavaFX), to see if the suspected bug was addressed.  If not, provide a [mcve] (please read and understand the linked page), that is specialized minimal code that reproduces only the issue via copy and paste with no change or addition.

Comment: Playing around with `TreeView` a little bit, I only saw missing graphics when I set the graphic of the `TreeItem`s. If I let the `TreeCell` be fully responsible for the graphics, I didn't notice any problems (though I may have simply missed it, as the missing graphics from the former approach happened rarely). It makes more sense for the `TreeCell` to be responsible for the graphics, anyway. It limits the number of nodes to the number of cells, instead of having potentially thousands of nodes in memory because they're associated with the items.

Comment: In my opinion, giving `TreeItem` a `graphic` property was an API mistake.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/JonathanGiles/scenic-view to check whether the scenegraph is wrong, or the rendering is broken.

Answer (score 1):

We tried Slaws approach and created a new graphic in the updateItem method whenever it is called.

With this the problem was gone. Voilá!

Maybe Slaw is also right that TreeItem should not have a graphic property. Nevertheless, thanks to all!